# Reading 2 text files and sending the newer text to new txt file

Tags: c#

is there a way in C# to read 2 seperate text files and which ever is the newer text place into a new text folder? and have possibly loop constantly to look into them?

Comment: Yes it is.  Research `FileStream` and `FileSystemWatcher`.

Comment: You don't need to read them to see which one is newer (unless there is something in the content that is more accurate for your needs than the "LastModified" timestamp of the file)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `GetLastWriteTime` property of a file to determine which one is newer, and you can use `File.Copy` (or `File.Move`) to place it into a new folder:

```
static void CopyNewestFileToLocation(string fileOne, string fileTwo, string destination)
{
    // Argument validation
    if (fileOne == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(fileOne));
    if (fileTwo == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(fileTwo));
    if (destination == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(destination));

    if (!File.Exists(fileOne)) throw new FileNotFoundException(
        "File specified for fileOne parameter does not exist", fileOne);
    if (!File.Exists(fileTwo)) throw new FileNotFoundException(
        "File specified for fileTwo parameter does not exist", fileTwo);

    if (!Directory.Exists(destination))
    {
        try
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(destination);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var msg = $"Unable to create specified directory: {destination}" + 
                      $"\nException Details:\n{e}";

            throw new ArgumentException(msg);
        }
    }

    // Find newest file and copy it
    if (File.GetLastWriteTime(fileOne) > File.GetLastWriteTime(fileTwo))
    {
        File.Copy(fileOne, Path.Combine(destination, Path.GetFileName(fileOne)));
    }
    else // TODO: decide what to do if they're equal
    {
        File.Copy(fileTwo, Path.Combine(destination, Path.GetFileName(fileTwo)));
    }
}
```

**Example Usage**

```
CopyNewestFileToLocation(@"f:\public\temp\temp.txt", @"f:\public\temp\temp2.txt", 
    @"f:\public\temp\newLocation");
```

Comment: What if the write times are at the same time?

Comment: it hits the else.

Comment: True, there are many improvements that can be made, this is just a quick sample.